# Android usethe same alertdialog and set different setPositiveButton content

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, alert

I have many "extends fragment" files.

I want to set alert Dialog in the AppUtility to share different fragment files to used.

they have to call the saveAlertDialog when the button click in different fragment.

But I want to overwrite the setPositiveButton.

Because they have replace difference fragment, or they call finish Activity.

How can I use the share function (saveAlertDialog) and overwrite in different fragment files?

My App Utility fils have below code:

```
public static AlertDialog saveAlertDialog( Context mContext  ) {

    // Dialog style
    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.diary_save_alert));
    tv.setTextSize(30);
    tv.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
    ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext,      R.style.customAlertDialog);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextThemeWrapper);
    builder.setCustomTitle(tv);
    builder.setPositiveButton(mContext.getString(R.string.save), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            // VVVVVVV it have problem.
            //mContext.finish();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(mContext.getString(R.string.not_save), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
```

My different fragment files. like below:

```
AlertDialog dialog = AppUtils.saveAlertDialog(mContext);
```

But I need to overwrite setPositiveButton to set different content in different fragment files.

like replace to BFragment , or Cfragment or finish the Activity.

```
fragment = new BFragment();
if (fragment != null) {

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.diary_frame_container, fragment, "BFragment").addToBackStack("BFragment").commit();                
} else {

    Log.e(TAG, "Error in creating fragment");
}
```

Have anyone know how to design the pattern?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DialogUtils` class write the below functions

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Context context, String title, String message, final DialogClickListener dialogBtnClickListener, String positiveButtonText, String negativeButtonText) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));

        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_small);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
            alert.setTitle(title);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            alert.setMessage(message);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(positiveButtonText)) {
            alert.setPositiveButton(positiveButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (dialogBtnClickListener != null) {
                        dialogBtnClickListener.onDone(null, true, null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(negativeButtonText)) {
            alert.setNegativeButton(negativeButtonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (dialogBtnClickListener != null) {
                        dialogBtnClickListener.onDone(null, false, null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        alert.show();
    }

    public static interface DialogClickListener {
        public void onDone(String stringMetadata, boolean isPositive, EditText editText);
    }
```

**Usage**

Now in your fragment class use them as

```
DialogUtils.showMessageDialog(getContext(), "title", "content", new DialogUtils.DialogClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDone(String stringMetadata, boolean isPositive, EditText editText) {
                        if (!isPositive) {
                            // if negative button is clicked
                        }else {
                           // positive button clicked
                    }
                }, "Ok", "cancel");
```

**Edit**

For getting the alert dialog instance You can go with either choices below:

You can either set the return type of `showMessageDialog()` to `Dialog` **OR** Make the interface `onDone()` have a extra parameter for dialog instance (By the way the extra parameter would not be a good idea as soon as one of the buttons are clicked dialog dissmisses automatically)

For the first suggestion to work, you have to make some changes as below

Since there is no any `cancel()` or `dismiss()` method from `AlertDialog.Builder` Class
So Instead of `AlertDialog.Builder` use `AlertDialog` instance.

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much. If use this metohd, how can I call the alert dismiss in fragment class? Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome :) ! I have edited my answer plz take a look , also if you like my answer can you accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you very much.You are help me very much :P